# How to block emoticons from input text field in codeignitier

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I want to make input text field in such a way that it will block emoticons entry in text input field. I have made validation on controller for particular route by passing.Is it is a right way to block emoticons.

Controller code.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('registration', 'Registration', 'required|alpha_numeric');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('odometer', 'Odometer', 'required|alpha_numeric');
```

view code:

```
<input type="text" name="odometer" placeholder="Odometer" class="form-control profileControl  odometer required number" id="odometer-<?php echo $vehicle_count; ?>" value="<?php echo $vehicle->intCarOdometer ?>"/>

<input type="text" placeholder="Registration" name="registration" class="form-control profileControl  registration required" id="registration-<?php echo $vehicle_count; ?>" value="<?php echo $vehicle->vchCarRegistration ?>" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"/>
```

Comment: yes it works but also you can remove it before sending to server on click with jquery

Comment: alphanumeric validation  on text input is right way to block emoticons?

Comment: no, it maybe exists some character that required.

Comment: can i add this script in view ?

Comment: yes now it is `onclick` you can change it to `onkeyup` the `input`

Comment: if i want to do it for muiltiple text input

Comment: now I edited my answer check it.

Comment: I have implemented your edited script code but its not for me.

Comment: move to chat... [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174138/discussion-between-abdulahmad-matin-and-priyanegi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*You can remove emoticons before sending to the server with jquery.*

***test this code.***

```js
var ranges = [
  '\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]', // U+1F300 to U+1F3FF
  '\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f]', // U+1F400 to U+1F64F
  '\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff]'  // U+1F680 to U+1F6FF
];

setTimeout(removeInvalidChars, 100);
function removeInvalidChars() {
  var str = $('.valid-text').val();
 
  str = str.replace(new RegExp(ranges.join('|'), 'g'), '');
  $(".valid-text").val(str);
 setTimeout(removeInvalidChars, 100);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myinput" class="valid-text" type="email" name="myinput" value="  value 1 2 3 ? / "></input>
```

Comment: 10 ms for timeout is way too fast (performance issues). 100 would probably be a better value

Comment: 100 is very long maybe between this 100ms user save the data and send it to the server.

Comment: I don't see it possible to type the some text in the input and then send the form in 100ms from keyboard and mouse. Not to mention that the emoticons can be removed when the form gets submitted.

Comment: Now it is 100ms. Thanks